# GNU "install" -d flag -- how's it work?

Tags: coreutils

I'm trying to write a makefile rule to copy a directory, maintaining its structure, and since all the other rules in our makefiles use `install`, I wanted to be consistent.

In the manpage, it says:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    install [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
>    install [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
>    install [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...
>    install [OPTION]... -d DIRECTORY...
>
>    -d, --directory
>           treat all arguments as directory names; create all components of
>           the specified directories
> ```

OK, that sounds like what I need... but the flags don't make sense. How do you specify the destination directory to install to?

I tried doing a basic test by making an arbitrary directory structure on my local hard disk:

```
~>tree test
test
├── a
│   └── b
│       └── c
│           └── e.txt
└── d

4 directories, 1 file
```

And then running `install -d` and looking at what was created:

```
~>install -d test test2
~>tree test2
test2

0 directories, 0 files
```

Nothing happened!

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Googling "gnu install -d flag" isn't bringing me much.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It looks like the `install -D` command is actually what I want.

Manpage:

> -D     create all leading components of DEST except the last, then copy SOURCE to DEST

Works great, except you have to specify every file individually.

Comment: I was excited right up until the end, "you have to specify every file individually". Guess I'll stick with `cp -r`

Comment: Does the install command have an equivalent to `cp -r`?

Comment: Thanks for explaining how -D worked for you.  I found the man page description confusing never having used this utility before.

Answer (score 17):

`install -d` is just used to create directories. You told it to create two directories, `test` and `test2`. `test` already existed, so all it needed to do was make `test2`. I don't think `install` supports copying entire directory trees; it's normally used on files. You probably need to use `cp`

Comment: Basically, `install -d` is the same as `mkdir` except that you can specify the mode, owner, SELinux context, and group all at once.

Comment: I would say `install -d` is like `mkdir -p`

Answer (score 6):

Usually what you want is to install files at right folder, without repeating your self. You can use find and install to help to keep your installation scripts more DRY

```
find SOURCE/ -type f -exec install -vDm 755 {} THERE/{} \;
```

Comment: Wy not hust `cp -r`?

Comment: With install you can control mode and there are more options that cp doesn't

Comment: With the command as-is, a `SOURCE/foo.txt` file will be copied to `THERE/SOURCE/foo.txt`, which may not be what you want?

Comment: This command can be made to behave like `cp -r` if you change the working directory to `SOURCE/` before running `find` on it and make `THERE/` an absolute path: `SOURCE=some_dir/; THERE=some_other_dir/; THERE="$(readlink -f "$THERE")"; pushd "$SOURCE"; find ./ -type f -exec install -vDm 0755 {} "$THERE"/{} \; ; popd;`.