# Using install -D in Makefile

Tags: compiling, make, coreutils

I'm trying to edit a Makefile that contains:

```
...
install -d $(DESTDIR)/usr/lib/myApp
install -d $(DESTDIR)/usr/lib/myApp/scripts
install -t $(DESTDIR)/usr/lib/myApp/scripts \
    src/scripts/ap.sh \
    src/scripts/connect.sh \
    src/scripts/devices.sh \
    src/scripts/create_ap \
    src/scripts/scan.sh
...
```

After reading [this Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21260/gnu-install-d-flag-hows-it-work), I got the idea that I could replace all that with:

```
install -D src/scripts/* $(DESTDIR)/usr/lib/myApp/scripts
```

But the above gives me an error saying:

> install: target
>   '/var/lib/jenkins/data/workspace/network-service_build-test@2/build/debian/myApp-service-network/usr/lib/myApp/scripts/network'
>   is not a directory

Am I misunderstanding the use of the `-D` flag here? I'm thinking it should move my files to the path specified and create the folders if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you need

```
install -t "$(DESTDIR)/usr/lib/myApp/scripts/network" -D src/scripts/*
```

This will create `$(DESTDIR)/usr/lib/myApp/scripts/network` (including intermediate directories) and copy the files `src/scripts/*` there.

Testing (with extra verbosity turned on):

```
$ touch file-{1,2,3,4}
$ install -v -t test/dir -D file-[1-4]
install: creating directory 'test'
install: creating directory 'test/dir'
'file-1' -> 'test/dir/file-1'
'file-2' -> 'test/dir/file-2'
'file-3' -> 'test/dir/file-3'
'file-4' -> 'test/dir/file-4'
```

This works with GNU `install` from coreutils 8.25, but fails with coreutils 8.4.  For older coreutils implementations, do it in two steps:

```
install -d "$(DESTDIR)/usr/lib/myApp/scripts/network"
install -t "$(DESTDIR)/usr/lib/myApp/scripts/network" src/scripts/*
```

... or something similar.

Comment: Didn't mean to include the `network` change in the question, that was another change I was making (will remove). I'm still getting the same error with this command for some reason https://pastebin.com/UCr8L9Bm

Comment: Yet if I run `install -d $(DESTDIR)/usr/lib/myApp/scripts/network` before the command you posted it seems to work fine. It must be something unique to our build system?

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride I can reproduce your problem with an older version of `install`. I'm using GNU `install` from coreutils 8.25 (which works), and my failing `install` is on coreutils 8.4.  Either upgrade your coreutils, or do it in two steps.